# Knockout Js Radio Bindings not setting Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Here is the documentation I'm looking at : [Example Adding Radio Buttons](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html#example-adding-radio-buttons)

It says:

> KO will set the element to be checked if and only if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s value attribute

Which I have done in this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AV4s2/)

```
self.radioValue = ko.observable(1);
```

and the HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="teloremail" value="1" data-bind="checked: radioValue" />
```

For me, this doesn't automatically set the radio to `checked`

Any reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the radio button node’s `value` attribute is `string`, so you need to store the value as `string` also in your observable:

```
self.radioValue = ko.observable("1");
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8wzz/).

[The example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html#example-adding-radio-buttons) also uses a string: `"almond"`.